# Hibernate cascade One to Many doesn't connect child with parent properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jhipster, mapstruct

I have a Java API (using Spring Framework) that is used by my front-end to create new parent objects (json) that has a list of new child objects in them like this:

```
parent = {
    children: [
    {
        childName: 'name1'
    },
    {
        childName: 'name2'
    }]   
}
```

As you can see no IDs are there, since I am about to save them, and the database should generate IDs.

The Parent entity has this code in the backend:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
```

After I call the repository 'save' operation on the Parent I can find the Child elements in the database (so cascade worked), but the 'parentId' column of the child in the database is null and therefore when I GET the parent, its list of children shows up as empty.

I can solve that by doing something like this in my service class:

```
repository.save(parent);
parent.getChildren().forEach((child) -> child.setParent(parent));
```

and it works because (I guess) by that time the parent has had an ID generated for it by the database, so the child table can use that ID for its parentId column. It works but it feels like this should be a standard One-to-many relationship and should be handled automatically by the framework in some prettier way than this. So my question is: What am I missing?

Is there some way that Hibernate can automatically populate the child entities 'parentId' column when saving them during the Cascade operation?

*Edit:*
This may in fact be caused by MapStruct that I use to map DTOs to POJOs and back. Not sure yet, but will keep investigating (see relevant link: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1068)

Comment: Your guess is wrong. The entity doesn't store the ID of the parent. It stores a reference to the parent object. You can do that before saving the parent. But you must do it: it's your responsibility, and not JPA's. By specification.

Comment: Can you show your annotation in child class to reference parent? Are you calling save operation on child or Parent?

Comment: @Rohit I save the Parent. 
JBNizet What I meant was that the child database table stores a foreign key to the parent table using the parent.id, but I'm aware, like you say, that the Java class has a reference to the entire parent object.
I have tried clarifying my post, sry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, and it's not a Hibernate issue really, sorry.

The problem is that I use MapStruct to have simpler front-end objects to work with. This separates objects into the POJOs and their respective DTO object. The DTO object doesn't have references to entire other objects, they just have some of the more relevant parts copied into them to make the json simpler.

so ChildDTO for example only has

```
{ 
    name : 'name',
    parentId: '1'
}
```

and then MapStruct is used when a call comes from front-end to backend, transforming the DTO into a real Java object, finding the parent by id in database ('ish'), and adding it to the child. But it doesn't by default know to add the parent reference to child elements that don't have parentId set, *even if they come in as part of a parent* (!). And because of this, in the Java Child class - the parent reference is null.

There are at least two solutions:

**MapStruct solution:**

Add custom mapping code to the MapStruct mappers to manually set the parent reference of all child elements that are sent in as part of a parent. See [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings)

**Java solution:**

add the parent reference to all children manually after MapStruct has run, but before saving to database:

```
// MapStruct first maps the DTO to a real Parent object, then:
parent.getChildren().forEach((child) -> child.setParent(parent));
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

Comment: I have tried second solution and it is still not working for me,  I am getting below exception during save - org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.invenio.loyalty.rewardservice.domain.Item I am using spring data jpa

Comment: @AniketKalamkar make sure you have fetched the parent from the repository before saving it. If you only have it as a java object then it's counted as a "detached entity". By making for example Parent parentFromDatabase = parentRepository.get(parent.id) then that object is now "attached" and can be saved.

Comment: I found the issue. it was happening since my DTO to domain was populating my child entities @id field as well due to same name between domain and DTOs. Now i have ignored that mapping, it started working fine since it is new object and id is blank so JPA is considering it as persist and using generator to generate new value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basics on how to create your entities and add children. As you will see, that you will not have to iterate over children and set parent's reference there.

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Children
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Parent")
    private List<Children> children;

    public List<Children> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {
        this.children= children;
    }

    public Children addChildren(Children child) {
        getChildren().add(child);
        child.setParent(this);

        return child;
    }

    public Children removeChildren(Children child) {
        getChildren().remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);

        return child;
    }
}
```

Now create parent object and call addChildren to set references properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly how my code looks. But you see; I'm not creating the parent, the children or adding children to parents in my Java backend, it happens in the front-end code. All I get is a full json of the new parent and its list of new children - straight to my backend endpoint. So I don't actually call "addChildren()" anywhere, the parent java class and its java children are parsed from the json, then I directly call "parentRepository.save(parent)" on that.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution - was sitting with same issue for days, I have a cascading oneToOne, oneToMany etc, setup to generate a pretty extensive xml. I still had to add cascading to the parent.

```
GrandParent finalGrandParent = grandparent;
grandparent.getParent().getChildren().forEach(child -> child.setParent(finalGrandParent.getParent()));
```